# What is the Gxt 3.1.1 way to implement Dialog.getHideButton() as was supported in Gxt 3.0.0?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gxt

I have the following piece of code for a project originally built on gxt 3.0.0 framework.

```
msgBoxInterim.addHideHandler(new HideHandler() {
                    public void onHide(HideEvent event) {
                        if(event != null && event.getSource() != null) {
                            Dialog btn = (Dialog) event.getSource();                            




                                if (btn != null && btn.getHideButton() != null && btn.getHideButton().getItemId() != null &&
                                        btn.getHideButton().getItemId().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {

                                callService();
                                timer.cancel();
                                logoffTimer.cancel();
                                interimTimer.cancel();
```

This code's intention to use a dialog's getHideButton is not supported in Gxt 3.1.1 and its throwing cant find getHideButton() error. What is the way to implement the same functionality in gxt 3.1.1 ? Please support by code snippets.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.addDialogHideHandler(new DialogHideHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onDialogHide(DialogHideEvent event) {
    if (event.getHideButton().equals(PredefinedButton.OK)) {
      // user clicks ok
    } else if (event.getHideButton().equals(PredefinedButton.CANCEL)) {
      // user clicks cancel
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That answered my doubt. Thanks a lot. One thing, Do I still need to write: 'msgBoxInterim.addHideHandler(new HideHandler() {
                    public void onHide(HideEvent event) {
                        if(event != null && event.getSource() != null) {
                            Dialog btn = (Dialog) event.getSource();' 
Or the dialog.addDialogHideHandler is enough for the whole handling thing .

Comment: No, I usually use the code above to check the pressed button.

Comment: Ok. But if I use both the handlers like in my code put above your code will it be wrong to use handlers cascaded like that.